# NO Javascript ASP.NET MVC - Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a mobile version of a website for devices which do not support Javascript at all. I'm looking for a calendar in MVC that doesn't make use of jquery library. Any idea?

Comment: you could make the server spit one out and make **lots** of post backs. what devices have no javascript at all and **why** are you developing for them?

Comment: What do you want it to do? Without Javascript, all you can have is a link.

Comment: Are you talking about proxy-browsers, like Opera Mini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show (and then submit ofcourse) a calendar in mobile browsers without javascript support, for example in proxy-browsers like Opera Mini. Then you can do the following trick with  fields - create calendar html markup and put radiobuttons behind each day

```
<input type="radio" name="calendar" value="15">
<input type="radio" name="calendar" value="16">
...
```

so once user will select some day, hidden radio button will be checked. And once user submit the form, all the data (selected day) will be submitted as part of the form. 
You can take a look on similar javascript-free star-rating widget: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/08/24/developing-an-accessible-star-ratings-widget/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have JavaScript enabled, why do you want to show a Calendar? The Calendar is meant to be a nice client side validation, which validates ranges and format.

If you can't have client side validation, then there is no use..

Put a TextBox and let the user enter the date he wants, then validate it server side. I think that is more usable that expecting the user to click a lots of times (and making lot of postbacks!) to change the month or year.